# When developing a library for PlatformIO and ESP32, what ifdef macro name can determine if compiling using PlatformIO?

Tags: c, embedded, platformio

When developing a library for PlatformIO and ESP32 (but also other platforms/environments), what ifdef macro name can be used to determine if the code is being compiled using PlatformIO?

For example, `#ifdef ESP32` can be used to determine whether the build target is an ESP32. Is there a similar `#ifdef PLATFORM_IO` macro that PlatformIO automatically sets that determines whether it's being built using PlatformIO?

I tried Googling for a macro set by PlatformIO, but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your own in [`build_flags`](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/sections/env/options/build/build_flags.html).  Since such a macro would be defined in platformio.ini, it would be implicit that it is a PlatformIO build environment.

Otherwise inspect platformio.ini, there may already be a suitable macro. [This](https://community.platformio.org/t/predefined-pre-preprocessor-directive-to-differentiate-between-arduino-ide-and-platformio/11183) suggests that `PLATFORMIO` may be defined, further suggests: `pio run -v` or `pio run -t envdump` to check macros predefined in the build environment.  YMMV - I'm just Googling this stuff!